# $(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\times(\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j)=\bigcap_{(i,j)\in I\times J}A_i \times B_j$ A Book of Set Theory Exercises 1.6 6a)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

We are presented with notation that requires some interpretation as it is not explicitly given on how to interpret it.

$$\bigcap_{(i,j)\in I\times J} A_i \times B_j$$

I have come up with two formulations.

$$\{(x,y)|\forall i \forall j((i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow (x,y)\in A_i\times B_j)\}$$
and
$$\{(x,y)|\forall i(i\in I\Rightarrow x\in A_i)\wedge\forall j(j\in J\Rightarrow y\in B_j)\}$$

I need to show
$$(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\times(\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j)=\bigcap_{(i,j)\in I\times J}A_i \times B_j$$

And we have by definition that $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\{x|\forall i(i\in I\Rightarrow x\in A_i)\}$, where $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an indexed family of classes.

If we use the bottom formulation, we're just done, but if we use the top formulation then I struggle how you can show what is necessary.

Edit:
In response to Hamdiken's answer I further clarify my problem.

Indeed from the above formulation we may reach
$$\forall i\forall j((i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow x\in A_i)$$

but saying that we may deduct further
$$\forall i(i\in I \Rightarrow x\in A_i)$$
is an appeal to intuition based in the idea $A_i$ doesn't depend on $j$.
We may try to assume $a\in I$, for an arbitrary $a$, in order to reach $x\in A_a$. But this fails because we can never be quite sure that we may use modus ponens to derive the consequent for it *requires* that we have an element in $J$; unless we say $J$ is non-empty and so we may already have some $b\in J$ tucked away for use later on, which I guess makes sense since $J$ is an index class, and so we would want (or maybe by definition) $J$ be non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(x,y)\in \bigcap_{(i,j)\in I\times J}{A_i \times B_j}$, that is
$$\{(x,y)|\forall i \forall j,(i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow (x,y)\in A_i\times B_j)\}$$
We can rewrite it as
$$\{(x,y)|\forall i \forall j,(i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow (x\in A_i\wedge y\in B_j)\}$$

Since $p\implies (q\wedge r)\iff (p\implies q)\wedge (p\implies r)$ we get
$$\{(x,y)|\left[\forall i \forall j,(i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow x\in A_i\right]\wedge \left[\forall i \forall j,(i,j)\in I\times J\Rightarrow y\in B_j\right]\}$$

Since $A_i$ doesn't depend on $j$, and $B_j$ doesn't depend on $i$, we get that
$$\{(x,y)|\left[\forall i,(i\in I)\Rightarrow x\in A_i\right]\wedge \left[\forall j,(j\in J)\Rightarrow y\in B_j\right]\}.$$

Using the intersection (since it's for every $i$ and $j$)
$$\{(x,y)|\left[(\forall i,(i\in I)\Rightarrow x\in A_i)\Rightarrow x\in \cap_i A_i\right]\wedge \left[(\forall j,(j\in J)\Rightarrow y\in B_j)\Rightarrow y\in \cap_j B_j\right]\}$$
From which
$$\{(x,y)|\left[x\in\cap_i A_i\right]\wedge \left[y\in \cap_j B_j\right]\}\implies (x,y)\in \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \right)\times\left(\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j \right) $$

Comment: I think by just citing that the index class is non-empty clears everything up. Let me know what you think.